# Sequelize order by a specific value

Tags: sequelize.js

How can I order by a specific value for a column? In php eloquent I'm doing:

```php
 [...]
 ->orderByRaw("FIELD(UserID, 123) desc")
 [...]
```

JS:

```js
[..]
  order: [
     // what goes here?
     // I do not want:
     // ['UserID', 'desc']
  ],
```

How to do the same with Sequelize? Nothing [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#ordering) seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`sequelize.fn`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-fn)

```
{
  // ...
  order: [
    [sequelize.fn('FIELD', sequelize.col('UserID'), 123), 'DESC']
  ]
  // ...
}
```

or use [`sequelize.literal`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#static-method-literal) (equivalent to writing raw queries)

```
{
  // ...
  order: sequelize.literal('FIELD(UserID, 123) DESC')
  // ...
}
```